# Systemd Service for jar file gets "operation timed out" error after few minues or stay in "activating mode"

Tags: linux, jar, systemd, rhel7, selinux

the service unit is:

```
[Unit]
Description=test
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/java -jar /home/ec2-user/test.jar
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

it starts fine for 1-4 minues. But later it fails:

tail  /var/log/messages:

```
Feb 27 18:43:44 ip-172-31-40-48 systemd: Reloading.
Feb 27 18:44:06 ip-172-31-40-48 systemd: Starting test...
Feb 27 18:44:06 ip-172-31-40-48 java: 5.1.73
Feb 27 18:44:06 ip-172-31-40-48 java: Starting the internal [HTTP/1.1] server on port 8182
Feb 27 18:49:06 ip-172-31-40-48 systemd: test.service operation timed out.Terminating.
Feb 27 18:49:06 ip-172-31-40-48 systemd: test.service: control process exited, code=exited status=143
Feb 27 18:49:06 ip-172-31-40-48 systemd: Failed to start test.
Feb 27 18:49:06 ip-172-31-40-48 systemd: Unit test.service entered failed state.
```

systemctl status test.service (while restarting- stays in activating mode):

```
test.service - Setsnew
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled)
Active: activating (start) since Sun 2015-03-01 14:29:36 EST; 2min 30s ago
Control: 32462 (java)
CGroup: /system.slice/test.service
```

systemctl status test.service (after fail):

```
test.service - test
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-02-27 18:49:06 EST; 18min ago
Process: 27954 ExecStart=/bin/java -jar /home/ec2-user/test.jar (code=exited, status=143)
```

- when running the jar in command line it works just fine.
- tried changing the jar location because I thought it's a permissions problem
- selinux is off

How can i fix this issue so I could start the jar on boot? there any alternatives? (RHEL7 do not include service command)

Answer (score 31):

You made the service type `forking`, but this service does not fork. It just runs directly. Thus systemd waited five minutes for the program to daemonize itself, and it never did. The correct type for such a service is `simple`.

You also disabled SELinux, which is another problem you should resolve.